# How can I determine whether the tooltip upward or downwards when using qtip2?

Tags: jquery, css, position, tooltip, qtip2

I want to change tooltip position when tooltip opened to upward.

qtip2 init;

```
jQuery('.tip').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).qtip({
       position: {
           at: 'center center',
           my: 'top center',
           adjust: {
               y: 15,
               method: 'shift flip'
           },
           viewport: $(window)
       },
       show: { delay: 500 },
       hide: { fixed: true, delay: 300, leave: false }
   }); 
});
```

My init code as above and when hover over to element, it show as below for downward tooltip;

[image]

it's ok but, it shows as below for upward tooltip

[image]

I want it show as like this;

[image]

How can i?

http://jsfiddle.net/crLqm851/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that `flip` is a wrong option to use in this case. Using `flipinvert` instead of `flip` makes the positions right :

```js
adjust: {
    y: 15, 
    method: 'shift flipinvert'
}
```

It also positions right when not defining `method` at all :

```js
adjust: {
    y: 15
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v68su257/**

The [**docs**](http://qtip2.com/plugins#viewport#position.adjust.method) says :

> The default "flip" type basically flips the tooltip when it goes
>   off-screen i.e. from top-right, to bottom-right etc. The "flipinvert"
>   type works the same way, *except when the flip happens it inverts the
>   adjust.x and adjust.y properties*.